# How to stop scroll() triggering events multiple times

Tags: jquery

Im using jquery.visible.js to detect when a DIV  is in view ( it starts the animation on plug in that has like a circle animation effect). But it keeps firing every time i use the scroll wheel, multiplying itself indefinitely and i cant find a way to stop it with off() or unbind()? thanks!

```
 // Check vertical for circliful using jquery.visible.js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($("#moreSection").visible(true)){


        // trigger circliful
        $('#myStat-1').circliful() // this wont stop firing

}
});
```

Comment: Both answers have some incorrect info, scroll does not fire on pixels but on display frame rate. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbNOdG?editors=001

Comment: thanks Shikkedial, very interesting to know

Answer (score 4):

as #Shikkediel pointed out `scroll()` gets fired on frame rate changes. so every scroll can trigger it hundreds of times.

you can do this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($("#moreSection").visible(true)){
        doActionAndStopScript();
    }
});

function doActionAndStopScript(){
    $('#myStat-1').circliful() // now it will fire once
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
}
```

you can only call the `unbind()` from outside the `$(window)`

Comment: hi Aryeh, yes i need it to fire only once when its scrolled into view and then the event listener destroyed if possible - im using jquery.visible.js to test the viewport

Comment: when what is scrolled in view? a certain part of the page?

Comment: also before i used another scroll dectioned plugin and it killed it with this: $('div').unbind('inview');

Comment: this is the site without the jquery.visible.js on: http://www.joewebsitedesigner.co.uk/test/ (its the div with the blue circle animation)

Comment: i edited my post. let me know if it works. don't forget to like the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

The `scroll` event will fire once for *every* pixel that is scrolled. To work around this behaviour you can use a timer which will only execute your logic *after* scrolling has stopped for x milliseconds. Try this:

```
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("#moreSection").visible(true)){
            $('#myStat-1').circliful();
        }
    }, 250);
});
```

250ms is normally long enough to wait to fire your code. You can tune this value as required.

Comment: hi there Rory, thanks for the help, but it still wont stop, im gonna upload the site in a few seconds..

Comment: Awesome, I use this method on 100ms delay, the scroll event is still fired only once.